# IOException : The port `\\.\COM3' does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, il2cpp

I am trying to Open a SerialPort in unity. It is working in editor and mono build. But when I build the game with iL2CPP scripting backend. It is throwing an exception with message `The port \\.\COM3 does not exist.`

Is this something related to Unity IL2CPP build?

**Unity player settings:**

**Scripting Runtime Version:** .Net 4.x Equivalent

**API compatibility Level:** .NET 4.x

```
public void OpenSerialPort()
{
    try
    {
        string ComPort = @"\\.\COM3"; //I even tried "COM3"
        int BaudRate = 9600;
        // Initialise the serial port
        SerialPort = new SerialPort(ComPort, BaudRate);
        SerialPort.ReadTimeout = ReadTimeout;
        SerialPort.WriteTimeout = WriteTimeout;
        SerialPort.DtrEnable = true;
        SerialPort.RtsEnable = true;
        // Open the serial port
        SerialPort.Open();

        Debug.LogError("SerialPort successfully opened!");
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        // Failed to open com port or start serial thread
        Debug.LogError("UnauthorizedAccessException: " + ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
    {
        // Failed to open com port or start serial thread
        Debug.LogError("ArgumentOutOfRangeException: " + ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        // Failed to open com port or start serial thread
        Debug.LogError("ArgumentException : " + ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        // Failed to open com port or start serial thread
        Debug.LogError("ArgumentException : " + ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        // Failed to open com port or start serial thread
        Debug.LogError("IOException : " + ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I read somewhere that \\.\ format is for two-digit ports

Comment: I event tried just "COM3". same exception

Comment: check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18796383/366064

Comment: In my case I am sure that com port exists .. because I am checked in Device Manager

Comment: @djkp Windows often doesn't handle COM ports too well.  Just because it shows in device manager doesn't mean its actually there.  For example, often if you change a COM port number in device manager, it will show immediately, but will not be available until after a reboot.   I work a lot with USB Serial ports from FTDI and find FTDI's FTPROG utility much more reliable to determine if a port is actually present.

Comment: Yeah I tried printing port as suggested by @Bijan. It prints COM3